# GWT SuperDevMode. Code server compilaction doesn't see classes from dependent project

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I've just migrated my GWT application to version 2.7 and I would like to start using the SuperDevMode. Accodring to this video: http://jeff-davis.blogspot.fr/2012/07/setting-up-gwt-25s-superdevmode.html I've configured the CodeServer but whey I run it I am getting following errors in the logs:

```
 Tracing compile failure path for type 'cern.edms.ui.client.service.CaddieServiceAsync'
      Errors in 'file:/C:/dev/Workspace/EDMS-APP/20151015_java7_gwt27/trunk/edms-ui/target/edms-ui-6.1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/cern/edms/ui/client/service/CaddieServiceAsync.java'
         Line 62: No source code is available for type cern.edms.ui.client.service.CaddieService; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 13: No source code is available for type cern.edms.ui.shared.auth.UserSession; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 41: No source code is available for type cern.edms.ui.shared.dto.common.NodeDTO; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 13: No source code is available for type cern.edms.ui.shared.dto.base.BaseDTO; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 27: No source code is available for type cern.edms.ui.shared.dto.caddie.CaddieDocumentDTO; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 34: No source code is available for type cern.edms.ui.shared.dto.item.SubItemDTO; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 48: No source code is available for type cern.edms.ui.shared.dto.IntegerListDTO; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 27: No source code is available for type cern.edms.ui.shared.util.AppEnums.CaddieAction; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 27: No source code is available for type cern.edms.ui.client.custom.data.BasicPagingLoadConfig; did you forget to inherit a required module?
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'cern.edms.ui.client.service.FavouritesServiceAsync'
      Errors in 'file:/C:/dev/Workspace/EDMS-APP/20151015_java7_gwt27/trunk/edms-ui/target/edms-ui-6.1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/cern/edms/ui/client/service/FavouritesServiceAsync.java'
         Line 13: No source code is available for type cern.edms.ui.shared.auth.UserSession; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 13: No source code is available for type cern.edms.ui.shared.dto.base.BaseDTO; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 41: No source code is available for type cern.edms.ui.client.service.FavouritesService; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 27: No source code is available for type cern.edms.ui.shared.dto.navigator.NavNodeListDTO; did you forget to inherit a required module?
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'cern.edms.ui.client.service.NavigationTreeServiceAsync'
      Errors in 'file:/C:/dev/Workspace/EDMS-APP/20151015_java7_gwt27/trunk/edms-ui/target/edms-ui-6.1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/cern/edms/ui/client/service/NavigationTreeServiceAsync.java'
         Line 27: No source code is available for type cern.edms.ui.shared.dto.navigator.NavNodeDTO; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 13: No source code is available for type cern.edms.ui.shared.auth.UserSession; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

The cern.edms.ui.shared.* packages come from external project added to GWT project by maven dependency.

Do you have any idea why they are not available when the code server is compiling the application?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: “I've just migrated my GWT application to version 2.7 and I would like to start using the SuperDevMode.” SuperDevMode is "on" by default when using DevMode in GWT 2.7; so you don't have to do anything, just run DevMode like you did before.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that. Please see also the answer added by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't have all my source folders in the classpath. I was trying to add only whole projects, intead of the source folders of these projects.

Source folders were added automatically (after importing dependent projects) to the classpath when I've started running the application as 'Web Application (Super Dev Mode)' instead of creating java application for Code Server.

Answer (score 0):

> The cern.edms.ui.shared.* packages come from external project added to GWT project by maven dependency.

Does that dependency contain the sources for those classes? If not, is there another jar (like a `-sources` classifier) that might have them?

Without the sources on the classpath (or source path), the GWT compiler can't compile the app.

Comment: Yes, it contains. In fact I have two eclipse projects (let's call them A and B). Project B is GWT project and has dependency on Project A defined in the pom file.

Comment: I added the project A to the CodeServer run configuration classpath (like the gwt-codeserver jar), but it also doesn't help.

Comment: Dependency isn't enough, the jar needs to contain sources, or you need to reference the project itself (and not use maven to handle that dependency, your IDE should do this automatically if all projects are open in it). If the error is still "no source found", then either your .gwt.xml files are messed up (i.e. does it compile normally?), or your project setup is still not right.